# PhoneGap: Clicking the Close Button on Google Maps InfoWindow does not Work

Tags: google-maps, cordova, infowindow

I am trying to include Google Maps on my mobile application.
When I am testing the application on a Web browser, everything is OK.
However, after compilation to an Android application (with Adobe PhoneGap), the infowindow of some point after clicked, then it cannot be closed, i.e. the close button on the top-right corner does not work (it is shown, but it is inactivated).

I think there is a general problem on opening infowindows, because I tried then to use commercial maps of Cyprus, from a company called [Geomatics](http://www.geomatic.com.cy/geomaps2/), and the infoWindow did not open at all!!!

Did anyone experience a similar issue? I would be really grateful for any help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not alone. Having multiple issues with `InfoWindow`s and `click` events on `Marker`s not firing in PhoneGap.